# BigQuery-: Unable to set values in "in unnest(@)" clause

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to use "in unnest()" clause using the BigQuery client through a java application where I've set the parameter type of a named parameter to array type because a list of values is to be sent in this clause. But I get error response:

```
 {
  "code" : 400,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Invalid query parameter type",
    "reason" : "invalid"
  } ],
  "message" : "Invalid query parameter type"
}
```

I got the same error when I tried using REST API where parameter type was set as

```
"parameterType": {
        "arrayType": {
          "type": "STRING"
}
```

How to set multiple values in "in unnest(@myparam)" clause ?

Answer (score 2):

From [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/querying-data#bigquery-query-params-arrays-api) it should be:

```
"parameterType": {
  "type": "ARRAY",
  "arrayType": {
    "type": "STRING"
   }
 }
```

Specifically, you also need to provide the `ARRAY` type.